# What if the property-owner gives his property to someone else other then his son?

Tags: zakat, property

If the property-owner gives property to some one else because:-

- His son does not pay zakat and takes interest
- Even then should the new-owner give the property to his son to ensure justice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially notice that giving alimony is Wajib or obligatory for parents (to give it to their children). It seems that there is not any specific age regarding its wojub (being wajib) and its basis is related to the ability of the children. Then he should support his son. But in regard to the inheritance it does not seem to be wajib to give to the children during his life. but his son would has a specified share after his farther died.

**Reference:**

- [www.askdin.com](http://www.askdin.com/thread11974.html)

Comment: If the father gives some property in his life to the other person,then is that person supposed to give back that property to the father's son to not be sinful?

Comment: I reckon it is not Wajib for that man (mate) to give back the gift. Since as far as I know, it is not Wajib to give back the gift (or money...) in case that they haven't any contract about that.